# Updating UITextView autocapitalizationType dynamically

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uitextview

I've got a blank test application with a UITextView, and I've added this delegate method:

```
func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) {
    if textView.text.hasPrefix("Cap") {
        textView.autocapitalizationType = .AllCharacters
    } else {
        textView.autocapitalizationType = .Sentences
    }
}
```

If the user types "Cap" at the start of the text, I want the textView to change to the .AllCharacters autocapitalizationType. If they remove that prefix, it should change back to sentences.

The code is called but not honoured and the keyboard doesn't change to reflect this. Any idea how I can nudge the textView to update the caps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resigning first responder to force the autocapitalizationType change to take effect isn't very clean. Instead, call UITextView.reloadInputViews() after changing autocapitalizationType. The keyboard stays open and uses the new autocapitalizationType value. According to the reloadInputViews() docs:

*You can use this method to refresh the custom input view or input accessory view associated with the current object when it is the first responder. The views are replaced immediately—that is, without animating them into place.*

That's exactly what I needed to temporarily select the shift key on the keyboard.

Answer (score 5):

Very interesting question. In fact the `autocapitalizationType` doesn't change while the keyboard is present but you can *nudge* it by resigning it and making it become the first responder again:

```
textView.autocapitalizationType = .AllCharacters
// slow operation
textView.resignFirstResponder() 
textView.becomeFirstResponder()
```

The problem is this process is slow so you will feel a big delay between every character so you should do this operation once.

```
func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) {
    if textView.text.hasPrefix("Cap") {
        if textView.autocapitalizationType != .AllCharacters {
            textView.autocapitalizationType = .AllCharacters
            textView.resignFirstResponder()
            textView.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
    } else {
        textView.autocapitalizationType = .Sentences
    }
}
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: This does in fact work, but unfortunately not really feasible for a production app as it's slow and expensive. I think it may be my only option though, so if I don't get any other answers I'll mark it as correct. Thanks!

Comment: Even the second approach is slow for you @ntesler? I tested here and it was fine since it wasn't triggering the resign/become first responder when the capitalization type was already `.AllCharacters`.

Comment: Definitely an improvement. I have a ton of code that is executed in textViewDidBegin/EndEditing but I can block it from executing when I use this workaround and that should help. I'll double check in Instruments that the system doesn't do anything too costly when this is called.