# UIKeyInput with All Caps Keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uikeyinput

I have created a custom text input view and am trying to force the keyboard to show all caps on the keyboard; similar to a `UITextField`. Here is what I have tried, but it isn't working for me:

```
class CustomInput: UIView, UIKeyInput {

    // UIKeyInput inherits this property
    var autocapitalizationType: UITextAutocapitalizationType { 
        get { return .AllCharacters } 
        set { } 
    }

}
```

I hoped that overriding the variable and only allowing `.AllCharacters` would force the keyboard to all caps, but that isn't the case. Any ideas how I can get the keyboard to all caps?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier (and more acceptable) to change the `UITextField` input characters to capitals instead?

Comment: I can make all the characters that show up on the screen uppercase with `text.uppercaseString`, but that isn't my issue. My issue is the keys in the keyboard showing lowercase. I want the keys to be uppercase.

Comment: @ZGski There is no `UITextField` involved. This is about a custom input view.

Answer (score 2):

I have this same problem in an app I'm currently working on. Have spent a fair amount of time trying to figure this out, especially since `autocorrectionType` and `keyboardType` both seem to work fine.

My current work-around is to make my custom view implement `UITextInput` instead of `UIKeyInput`, with dummy code for all unused properties and functions. Extremely ugly work-around but it's the only way I can get it to work, so I'm running with it.

Would be interested to see if anyone has insight into the underlying issue here.

Comment: I opened a radar for this a couple days after I posted the question. I haven't heard anything back from Apple yet.

Comment: Well that makes me feel good--played around with this extensively and at the end the only thing I could imagine was it was a bug.

Answer (score 1):

I hadn’t seen this, but recently ran into the same problem and concluded that the UIKit functionality is broken and does not work as described. I submitted a feedback report with sample project demonstrating the problem, where if the custom view is replaced with a UITextView (with no other changes) everything works as expected:

FB13298309 (Keyboard: `autocapitalizationType` property is erroneously ignored for custom UIView conforming to <UIKeyInput>)

I've confirmed that providing a dummy implementation of the `UITextInput` protocol does allow this to work (iOS 17.0 here).

However, I find that using `-reloadInputViews` as described in the answer to [Updating UITextView autocapitalizationType dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34914797/updating-uitextview-autocapitalizationtype-dynamically) does **not** work when dynamically changing the property value. I found it necessary to have the view `resignFirstResponder` and immediately `becomeFirstResponder` after changing this property value of my custom class (*e.g. in response to a button action*), otherwise the onscreen keyboard does not change state until after the next keypress.